# 400 bad request during axios call

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, components, bad-request

Not sure why but the POST request is coming back 400. Postman says my django backend is doing fine. It all happens at the post_flashcards method any help would be great and I am willing to show any other code as requested. although there shouldnt be the need to since this component acts mostly on its own.

```
class CreateFlashCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            collection_id: '',
            term: '',
            definition: '',
        }

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
     }  
    
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        this.post_flashcard()
    } 

    async post_flashcard() {
        const card = this.state;
        const col_id = parseInt(this.state.collection_id)
        try{
            await axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/flashcardsapp/${col_id}`, card)
            .then(response => console.log(response.status))
        }catch(er){
            console.log('ERROR in post_flashcard', er)
        }
    }
     
    
    render() { 
        const {title, collection_id, term, definition} = this.state
        return (
            
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
               <h2>Create a Card</h2>
               <label for="title">Enter Collection Title</label>
               <input type="text" name="title" value={title} onChange={this.onChange} ></input>
               <label for="collection_id">Enter Collection ID</label>
               <input type="number" name="collection_id" value={collection_id} onChange={this.onChange} ></input>
               <label for="term">Enter Term</label>
               <input type="text" name="term" value={term} onChange={this.onChange} ></input>
               <label for="definition">Enter Definition</label>
               <input type="text" name="definition" value={definition} onChange={this.onChange} ></input>
               <input type="submit"></input>
           </form>
        );
    }
}
 
export default CreateFlashCard;
```

Comment: Does the body of the 400 response contain any useful data? A 400 response indicates some kind of issue with the data sent, usually a data validation issue

Comment: What's the actual error coming back from the server? 400 is just the status code for a bad request

Comment: I things because your body contains the `collection_id`, so your server throws the 400 error.

Comment: Are you logged in/authorized when doing the axios call. Sometimes Django send a `400 Bad Request` response instead of `401 Unauthorized`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing post processing, you can convert the Data to Json format and send it.

```
   var post_data = {
    your_post_name: this.state
  };

  axios
    .post(url, JSON.stringify(post_data))
    .then((response) => {

      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

or

```
      axios
.post(url,JSON.stringify({your_post_name:this.state}))
        .then((response) => {

          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue state had typo in title needed to be collection_title.